# Not able to align my menu button on left side in header

Tags: html, css, sass, ionic2

I referred to my [button](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/components/#floating-action-buttons) to align left and right `start` and `end` key as per the above link. But i am not able to set my button as per the view in the link here is my output image

[image]

Here is my code

```
<ion-header class="home">
  <ion-navbar primary padding>
    <ion-row> 
      <ion-buttons start>
      <button menuToggle >
        <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
        
      </button>
      </ion-buttons>
        
      <ion-title>Auto Parts</ion-title>
        
      <ion-buttons end>
            <button> <ion-icon name="document"></ion-icon></button>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <button><ion-icon name="heart"></ion-icon></button>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <button><ion-icon name="cart"></ion-icon></button>
      </ion-buttons>
    </ion-row>
    
    <ion-row>
      <ion-searchbar (ionInput)="getItems($event)"></ion-searchbar>
    </ion-row>

  </ion-navbar>

</ion-header>
```

What I have tried so far is:

> float: right; and float: left;
>
> algin: right

but not able to get my button to left

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve that layout by using an `<ion-toolbar>` to place the search bar like you can see in [this plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/hBNWlQ?p=preview)

```
<ion-header class="home">
  <ion-navbar primary padding>
      <button menuToggle>
        <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
      </button>
      <ion-title>Auto Parts</ion-title>
      <ion-buttons end>
            <button> <ion-icon name="document"></ion-icon></button>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <button><ion-icon name="heart"></ion-icon></button>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <button><ion-icon name="cart"></ion-icon></button>
      </ion-buttons>
  </ion-navbar>
  <ion-toolbar primary>
      <ion-searchbar (ionInput)="getItems($event)"></ion-searchbar>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
```

**EDIT:**

> To hide both borders, the `no-border` attribute should be used on the
>   ion-toolbar. To hide the top or bottom border, the `no-border-top` and
>   `no-border-bottom` attribute should be used.

Comment: on doubt i am getting a line between my ion-navbar and ion-toolbar

Comment: I've updated the answer, you can remove that line by using the `no-border` attribute in the ion-toolbar.

Comment: i tried all the ways but still i am getting the border i tried inside the ion-toolbar and also ion-navbar

Comment: Have you tried with `no-shadow` in the header like this: `<ion-header no-shadow>`?

Comment: I'm not getting that line in the plunker... could you please update the plunker with your code, so I can take a look?

Comment: I am also not getting that line in plunker but in my browser i am getting wait i will update my pic

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121005/discussion-between-mohan-gopi-and-sebaferreras).